# ¿Mostrar la animación de carga mientras cargas perezosas del módulo?

Tags: angular, rutas, angular6

Mis principales rutas tienen perfilModulo cargado ligeramente en /profile así:

```js
{ 
     path: '', 
     component: HomeComponent 
    }, 
    { 
     path: 'profile', loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule' 
    }, 
    { 
     path: '**', 
     redirectTo: '', 
     pathMatch: 'full' 
    } 

}
```

Sin embargo, perfilModulo toma ~ 1,5 - 2 segundos para cargar, el cual es bastante lento. Me gustaría mostrar algún tipo de animación de carga mientras se carga mi módulo, ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Hola @Mario, te refieres al módulo como tal, o también de casualidad tienes algun servicio que se encargue de gestionar o cargar datos desde una API al módulo que haces referencia?

Comment: Tengo un resolve para traer permisos, pero eso se realiza en milisegundos. Lo que demora es la carga del modulo como tal, el archivo peso algo de 2mb, es un modulo regularmente grande. 

`{
        path: 'pedidos',
        loadChildren: 'app/modulos/pedidos/pedidos.module#PedidosModule',
        resolve: {
          menu: MenuResolve,
          breadcrumb: PedidosCaminoResolve
        },
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
      }`